# eth_chainId request fails during safeSdk.createTransaction fn call because of incorrect payload

Tags: gnosis-safe

I am using safe-core-sdk to create and propose transactions to the safe.

I am using the following code -

```
    function createTx(
     toAddress,
     calldata,
     value,
     safeAddress,
     account
    ){
    const web3Provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
        "https://arb-rinkeby.g.alchemy.com/v2/API_TOKEN"
    );
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(web3Provider);
    const safeOwner = provider.getSigner(account);

    const ethAdapter = new EthersAdapter({
        ethers,
        signer: safeOwner,
    });
    const safeSdk = await Safe.create({
        ethAdapter: ethAdapter,
        safeAddress: safeAddress,
    });
    const tx = await safeSdk.createTransaction({
        to: toAddress,
        data: calldata,
        value: value,
    });
    return tx;
```

function **createTx** when called throws the following error -

```
{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 43, "error": {"code": -32601, "message": "Unsupported method [{'method': 'eth_chainId', 'params': [], 'id': 1, 'jsonrpc': '2.0'}]. See available methods at https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/documentation/apis"}}
```

This is error is caused because POST request payload is incorrect, as seen below.

```
{method: {method: "eth_chainId", params: [], id: 1, jsonrpc: "2.0"}, id: 43, jsonrpc: "2.0"}
>>> 
id: 43
jsonrpc: "2.0"
method: {method: "eth_chainId", params: [], id: 1, jsonrpc: "2.0"}
```

I am unable to track down and fix it in the core-sdk, can anyone help me figure this out? Or is there any alternative method to this for creating SafeTransactions?

Comment: have you tried alchemy provider from ethers?

Comment: Where do you create your wallet and connect it to the provider?

Comment: Yup I think I was missing provider. I changed it to window.ethereum and it worked.

But now it throws another error - 
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid Multi Send contract address

I am on arbitrum-rinkeby. I guess I will have to add the address myself?

Comment: yes until https://github.com/gnosis/safe-deployments is released with arb rinkeby changes